# Wordpres Tinymce custom button (Gavick guide)

Tags: tinymce, editor, buttons

I'm trying to adda custom button to my editor following [this guide](https://www.gavick.com/blog/wordpress-tinymce-custom-buttons#tmce-section-1)

Can't get it to work. I've added the following code to my funcitons.php

```
  add_action('admin_head', 'gavickpro_add_my_tc_button');

function gavickpro_add_my_tc_button() {
    global $typenow;
    // check user permissions
    if ( !current_user_can('edit_posts') && !current_user_can('edit_pages') ) {
    return;
    }
    // verify the post type
    if( ! in_array( $typenow, array( 'post', 'page' ) ) )
        return;
    // check if WYSIWYG is enabled
    if ( get_user_option('rich_editing') == 'true') {
        add_filter("mce_external_plugins", "gavickpro_add_tinymce_plugin");
        add_filter('mce_buttons', 'gavickpro_register_my_tc_button');
    }
}

function gavickpro_add_tinymce_plugin($plugin_array) {
    $plugin_array['gavickpro_tc_button'] = plugins_url( '/kevin/editor_plugin.js', __FILE__ ); // CHANGE THE BUTTON SCRIPT HERE
    return $plugin_array;
}

function gavickpro_register_my_tc_button($buttons) {
   array_push($buttons, "gavickpro_tc_button");
   return $buttons;
}
```

and the following js file in my plugins folder kevin/editor_plugin.js

```js
    (function() {
        tinymce.PluginManager.add('gavickpro_tc_button', function( editor, url ) {
            editor.addButton( 'gavickpro_tc_button', {
                title: 'My test button',
                icon: 'wp_code',
           

     onclick: function() {
                editor.insertContent('Hello World!');
            }
        });
    });
})();
```

Comment: if it does not do what you expected, what does it do instead? Can you be more specific than it does not work? Is this in the block editor or the classic editor? The link in your question is to a support article for the gavick pro theme, have you asked their support routes? 3rd party theme dev support is off topic here so if this is specific to that theme then you can't ask here

Comment: Also are you sure you meant to add `kevin/` to the plugins_url call? This would make WP look for `wp-content/plugins/kevin/kevin/button-text.js`? This would also throw up 404 errors in your browsers dev tools error console that you could read.